# Collada file required components

Tags: 3d, collada

Hey guys I've read through the collada documentation the best I can. I am converting a proprietary 3d format to collada and I am wondering what library are REQUIRED. Currently I have `<library_geometries>`

It's not importing into sketchup but it also doesn't tell me why the import failed. I'm not that surprised I suspect I need a scene at least.

It would at least be nice to know what the min I need to put in is so I can see how things are working so far.

Comment: If you try loading it with [pycollada](https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada)/[meshtool](https://github.com/pycollada/meshtool), it will give you error details.

Comment: Pycollada/meshtool works great thank you. I also downloaded a trial of 3ds max which also tells me what errors are in the file. It also helped visualize the problem as it seemed to be the only viewer that was able to load up a bad model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the required libraries: 1) `<asset>`, `<library_geometries>`, `<library_materials>`, `<library_effects>`, `<library_visual_scenes>`, `<scene>`.

And I explain why. First of all, you need an `<asset>` to define your unit under `<unit>` element if it is meter or millimeter, whatever. Other than that, you have to say your up axis for 3d coordinates under `<up_axis>`. It is also good practice to give other asset information like contributor or creation time.

You have to define one `<instance_visual_scene>` under your `<scene>`. Without this information there will be no scene to show. And this instance has a reference for one `<visual_scene>` element, which is under `<library_visual_scenes>`. Visual scene has probably some child-nodes as `<node>` element, which has translation or rotation values to give the position of the geometry. Under `<node>`, there is a child element `<instance_geometry>`, which is combined with an `<instance_material>` through `<bind_material>`. `<instance_geometry>` has a reference for a `<geometry>` under `<library_geometries>`. And `<instance_material>` has a reference for a `<material>` under `<library_materials>`. `<material>` has a child element `<instance_effect>`. `<instance_effect>` has a reference for `<effect>` under `<library_effects>`.

The order is for geometry like `<scene>` -> `<instance_visual_scene>` -> `<visual_scene>` -> `<node>` -> `<instance_geometry>` -> `<geometry>`

And for material connection `<instance_geometry>` -> `<bind_material>` -> `<instance_material>` -> `<material>` -> `<instance_effect>` -> `<effect>`

Answer (score 0):

I installed collada using the .deb there was an issue with libboost-system1.49.0
after installing libboost -dev -all from the repositories it installed fine. this is were I got the .deb libboost-system1.49.0 just go to the mitsuba download collada will also be on the download page.